# Can anyone convert VBA script to AppSheet

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to go to from current selection to desired column with the same row of selected cell. I can do this in a simple VBA script in EXCEL but in sheets, their script is very different. I am not familiar with App Script and never used it. Can any one help convert below VBA to App script.

```
Range("AB" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
```

The above script is simply adding ROW number to AB, so if I am at row 100, the result is AB100 and it will select AB100.

Comment: So I guess the entire column for Apps Script is `sheet.getRange("AB1:AB" + sh.getLastRow())`

Answer (score 1):

#### Looping through column AB

```
function getAllValuesInColumnAB() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const values = sh.getRange("AB1:AB" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  //now you can loop through all of them with
  values.forEach((e,i)=>{
    //e is the value in each row
    //i + 1 is the row number
  })
}
```

- [apps script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)